# Error in Apple I manual's Wozmon listing or Hardware description?

Tags: 6502, apple

The [Apple I Operation Manual](https://archive.org/details/apple1manual) includes a full listing of Steve Wozniak's amazing 256 byte 6502 Hex Monitor, aka Wozmon, as well as some explanation of how to interact with the Apple I hardware.  My question is with regards to outputting a character to the display.  On page 8, it says:

> The sequences listed below are the routines used to read the keyboard or output to the display (the text uses an arrow to indicate the BPL will branch to the prior LDA).
>
> Read key from KBD:
>
> ```
>   LDA KBD CR (D0111)
> ⤤ BPL
>   LDA KBD DATA (D010)
> ```
>
> Output to Display:
>
> ```
>   BIT DSP (D012)
> ⤤ BPL
>   STA DSP (D012)
> ```

And later:

> DSP DATA D012
>
> Lower seven bits are data output, high order bit is "display ready" input (1 equals ready, 0 equals busy)

So the output logic is:  use `BIT` to check bit 7 of the value in the Display Data address (This is the PIA's PB7 line), and if that bit is 0 (`BPL` branches when flag `N` is not set), go back and read it again.  Stay in this loop until the display is ready (bit 7 of DSP Data is 1, so `BIT` sets `N` to 1, and `BPL` does not branch), the proceed to push the byte to the DSP Data address.

So far so good.  However, at the top of page 7, the Wozmon listing includes this:

```
FFEF 2C 12 D0    ECHO      BIT DSP        DA bit (B7) cleared yet?
FFF2 30 FB                 BMI ECHO       No, wait for display
FFF4 8D 12 D0              STA DSP        Output character.  Sets DA.
```

This seems to follow the explanation from page 8, except that it uses `BMI` (branch when `N` is set) instead of `BPL` (branch when `N` is NOT set), and the comment even indicates that it is waiting for bit 7 of DSP Data to be *cleared*, not set.

By comparison, the Wozmon code to read a character from the keyboard from Page 5 matches the description above:

```
FF29 AD 11 D0    NEXTCHAR  LDA KBD_CR     Key Ready?
FF2C 10 FB                 BPL NEXTCHAR   Loop until ready
FF2E AD 10 D0              LDA KBD        Load character. B7 should be '1'.
```

Here, Wozmon uses BPL just as the explanation says.

As San Bergmans notes in his excellent [explanation of Wozmon](https://www.sbprojects.net/projects/apple1/wozmon.php),

> Only upper case ASCII characters are accepted. Lower case characters are not recognized and are considered an error. Also bit b7 of every ASCII character is always set, whereas officially it should be cleared.

It would seem that Woz was using b7 as a flag, outputting it high and waiting for the display hardware to clear the flag, indicating that the next character could be output.  This makes me think that the Wozmon listing must be correct, and the description of the output logic and DSP Data address must be incorrect, but I have not been able to find confirmation of this.

Comment: I don't know the Apple hardware particularly well, but I do know Woz's code, and I'd trust that over descriptive documentation. ;) Have you tried this code in an emulator (or even on hardware if you're lucky enough to own it)?

Comment: I'm currently writing my own emulator, which is how I found this issue.  I agree that the code must be right, but I was surprised to find no other description online of the issue, and my 6502 (and Apple 1) experience is still limited, so I thought it would be worth asking here.  Looking at another emulator is a good idea though.

Comment: The use of `BPL` in the "Output to Display:" quote, certainly looks like either: a copy/paste (or, given that copy and paste didn't exist back then, code duplication) error, or; (more likely) it was written upon the incorrect false premise stated under the definition of `DSP` (i.e. the logic is inverted). It *is* surprising that no one seems to have seen this before, or if they have, then it really doesn't seem to be mentioned, or documented, anywhere. After Googling many many variations of "Apple I Operation Manual errata/error", I couldn't find anything. Nice catch..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial answer:

If you look at the schematics, both on page 7 and the very last page, you'll see that the PIA actual gets a pair of signals for the display, `/RDA` via a one-shot trigger to `CB1` as an input, and `CB2` as an output negated to `DA`. The latter is also looped back to `PB7`. The value `$A7` in the `DSP CR` display control register sets up the PIA to generate a pulse whenever the `DSP` register is read by the CPU.

On the second last page, you can see that `DA` is looped back to `/RDA` via a 74174 D-Flip-Flip `C7`, which has `MEM0` as a clock.

My interpretation of this is that originally the handshake with the display was intended to work in the same way as for the keyboard: `/RDA` would set bit 7 in the control register, so just like the keyboard loop

```
LOOP:   BIT KBD_CR
        BPL LOOP
        LDA KBD
```

the display loop would have been

```
LOOP:   BIT DSP_CR
        BPL LOOP
        STA DSP
```

waiting on the `/RDA` signal to be set in `C7` after the `MEM0` pulse.

However, for whatever reason, that then got changed: Instead of reading the **control** register `/RDA` signal, they found that it is sufficient (and maybe faster?) or necessary (because something else did not work?) to just wait on the triggered pulse of the PIA. So they corrected the code in the main text to use `DSP` instead of `DSP_CR`

```
LOOP:   BIT DSP
        BPL LOOP
        STA DSP
```

but forgot to change the `BPL` to `BMI`. Which they did do in the actual ROM code.

At least that's my reading. If someone has the Apple I hardware (or a re-creation), maybe they can check the signals and verify.

And if your intent is to write a faithful emulator, I guess you'll have to include PIA emulation including the `/RDA` signal, in case there is some Apple I program that uses that directly.

Comment: Excellent answer, that seems quite likely.  Accepted.  And there are a couple of other places where the code comments don't quite match the code, which I'll record in a separate answer, once Ben Eater releases his Wozmon video that documents one of them (available on Patreon now, on YouTube in a week).